# triggering an event with edible delay in javascript for html file

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have to trigger an event with a delay. The handler adds a border to any paragraph that is being read. The delay can be changed by the user. When I added the timeout, the border is never shown, while without the timeout it does. How can I trigger the event with delay?

```
window.onload = function() {
   init();
}

function init() {
    for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length - 1; i >= 0; i--)         {
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",     setTimeout(re, document.getElementById("input").innerHTML));
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseout", rl);
    };
}

function re(e) {    
var id=e.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).style.border = "thick solid blue";
}
function rl(e) {
 var id=e.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).style.border = "none";
}
```

Comment: 'Input' is which type of control?means label or textbox?

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ 
   var delay = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML; 
   setTimeout(re, parseInt(delay));
});
```

`setTimeout` is being invoked when adding the listener, instead of when the event is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method the second param should be `The number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code`. But looks like in your code that is missing.

Try to change this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",     setTimeout(re, document.getElementById("input").innerHTML));
```

to something like below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",     setTimeout(re, 1000, document.getElementById("input").innerHTML));
```

Hope this will resolve the issue!

Comment: document.getElementById("input").innerHTML is the delay that event has to be triggered with..

Comment: OK, then where is the param for for function `re(e)`? For `e` you have to pass the value as the 3rd param in `setTimeout ` call.

Comment: One more thing `input` is what type of element?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get textbox input you have to use id.value instead of id.innerHTML
change your code like below:

```
window.onload = function() {
   init();
}

function init() {
    for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length - 1; i >= 0; i--)         {
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",     setTimeout(re(this), document.getElementById("input").value));
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseout", rl(this));
    };
}

function re(e) { 
    e.style.border = "thick solid blue";
}
function rl(e) {
    e.style.border = "none";
}
```